# openssl giving me unknown option

Tags: bash, openssl

kindly asking help for this crazy behavior:

```
openssl x509 -noout -subject -in 01.pem
subject= ....
```

Above works, but when I try to run it for multiple files, it fails:

```
find . -name "*.pem" -exec openssl x509 -noout -subject -in {} +
unknown option ./01.pem
...
```

What is the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson "Your use of double quotes means the shell expands the wildcards" no, this is incorrect. Double quotes remove the special meaning of wild cards.

Comment: I find the same behaviour, but when I replace `+` with the traditional `\;`, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the solution is simple. `+` means that `find` collects the files it finds and adds several of them (as many as it can without overflowing the argument space) to the same `openssl` invocation. Since `openssl` only takes one file argument, this fails.

In this case, use `\;` instead of `+`.